# Get Element and ID, if any on mouseover with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am attempting to give my admins a **mouseover** of the element they are hovering over to give them a clue to what to edit, if anything.  Here is my code:

```
$(document).tooltip();
$(document).on('mouseover','*',function(){
  $(this).attr('title',$(this).prop('id'));
  console.log($(this));
}).on('mouseout',function(){
  $(this).attr('title','');
});
```

This works great for elements with an id.  What I need to get is a combination of **html** element and id (if any) on **mouseover**.

Comment: What do you mean by *"combo html element"*?

Comment: Not clear. On mouseover, you're setting the title of the element. But what should happen when there is no id?

Comment: what I am trying to get is the element (body,div,span, etc.) it will be helpful, but not necessary to have an id on the element

Comment: i think you want to get the element type name. If so then you can use code like `$(this).prop('nodeName')`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, when you hover over an element, you want the id of the element as well as the element type (tag name). If that's the case, then you can use the following:

```
 $(document).on('mouseover','*',function(){
      var id = this.id;
      var elementType = $(this).prop('nodeName'); // will give you element tag name
      // do something with id and elementType
    }).on('mouseout',function(){
      $(this).attr('title','');
    });
```

Comment: thanks to you guys I now know that there actually were other posts that ask the same question.  Should I delete my post?

Comment: @phpmydev You don't need to delete the post. If you accept the duplicate question, your question can serve as a signpost for others looking for the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to short that code using `this.id` instead of `$(this)...`
Also check your console and pick w/e you need from there and use `||` operator to pick the one that suits you best.

```
$(document).on('mouseover','*',function(){
  $(this).attr('title',(this.id || some_other_things || yet_another_one));
  console.log($(this));
  console.log(this);
}).on('mouseout',function(){
  $(this).attr('title','');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is not defined then  get the [`tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) property of the dom element.

```
$(this).attr('title', this.id || this.tagName);
```